# Cmd + T to open new tab position are unpredictable

Tags: macos, safari, tabs

Issue:
As written on the title of the question.

(Edit: Tabs sometimes open on the last position and sometimes open right next to current tab.)

[image: Cmd+T behavior]

Expectation:
New tab always open either next to current tab, or open on last position in tab list.

Comment: Your animated GIF is showing exactly what you describe in the *expectation*  If not, can you supply some context of how it's not working?

Comment: I edited the issue and the expectation, should make more sense now.

Comment: I can't tell from the gif what you're actually doing. If you open a link in a new tab it will open immediately right of the one you opened it from, unless you already opened one earlier, in which case it will open to the right of that one. If you use Cmd/T it should always open on the far right.

Comment: The gif is me pressing Cmd+T then Cmd+W repeatedly, the behavior isn't of what you said to be, my Safari sometimes opens the new tab after the current tab.

Comment: Why are you pressing Cmd-W repeatedly?  Also, be aware that if you don’t have an active tab open/selected, it will open on the far right.